# What to do with my error?

Tags: c#

In my calculation lines im getting the error "use of unassigned local variable ..." for lodgingFee, registrationFee, and days. Ive declared the variables in the beginning so i dont know what im supposed to do.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal days;
        decimal registrationFee;
        decimal lodgingFee;
        decimal total;
        decimal lodgingCal;

        string registration;

        if (workshopListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            registration = workshopListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

            switch (registration)
            {
                case "Handling Stress":
                    registrationTextBox.Text = "$1000";
                    days = 3;
                    registrationFee = 1000;
                    break;
                case "Time Managment":
                    registrationTextBox.Text = "$800";
                    days = 3;
                    registrationFee = 800;
                    break;
                case "Supervision Skills":
                    registrationTextBox.Text = "$1500";
                    days = 3;
                    registrationFee = 1500;
                    break;
                case "Negotiation":
                    registrationTextBox.Text = "$1300";
                    days = 5;
                    registrationFee = 1300;
                    break;
                case "How to Interview":
                    registrationTextBox.Text = "$500";
                    days = 1;
                    registrationFee = 500;
                    break;
            }
        }

        string lodging;

        if (locationListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            lodging = locationListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

            switch (lodging)
            {
                case  "Austin":
                    lodgingTextBox.Text = "$150";
                    lodgingFee = 150;
                    break;
                case "Chicago":
                    lodgingTextBox.Text = "$225";
                    lodgingFee = 225;
                    break;
                case "Dallas":
                    lodgingTextBox.Text = "$175";
                    lodgingFee = 175;
                    break;
                case "Orlando":
                    lodgingTextBox.Text = "$300";
                    lodgingFee = 300;
                    break;
                case "Phoenix":
                    lodgingTextBox.Text = "$175";
                    lodgingFee = 175;
                    break;
                case "Raleigh":
                    lodgingTextBox.Text = "$150";
                    lodgingFee = 150;
                    break;
            }
        }

        lodgingCal = lodgingFee * days;
        total = registrationFee + lodgingCal;


        totalTextBox.Text = total.ToString("c");

     }

    }
}
```

Comment: You've declared them, but the code gives no guarantee that you've assigned them. That is what the compile error tells you. And yes, you need to assign values to variables before you can use them.

Comment: Re-read the error message. It's not about declaration...

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Use of unassigned local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484645/error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialized the variable before to use them.

```
decimal days = 0.0;
decimal registrationFee = 0.0;
decimal lodgingFee =0.0;
decimal total = 0.0;
decimal lodgingCal= 0.0;
```

Comment: So when im using decimal, double,etc do i always need to specify their value?

Comment: No that is only if there is some path in the logic where you don't assign them, and then use them. Like is the case here. Suppose you raise an exception in the default case of the switch statement , then the default assignment is not needed per se.

Answer (score 1):

Add a default case to your switch statements where you can raise an exception or assign some error value to those variables.

```
switch (registration)
        {
            case "Handling Stress":
                registrationTextBox.Text = "$1000";
                days = 3;
                registrationFee = 1000;
                break;
            case "Time Managment":
                registrationTextBox.Text = "$800";
                days = 3;
                registrationFee = 800;
                break;
            case "Supervision Skills":
                registrationTextBox.Text = "$1500";
                days = 3;
                registrationFee = 1500;
                break;
            case "Negotiation":
                registrationTextBox.Text = "$1300";
                days = 5;
                registrationFee = 1300;
                break;
            case "How to Interview":
                registrationTextBox.Text = "$500";
                days = 1;
                registrationFee = 500;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ApplicationException("oh no I don't want this");
        }
```

You are getting the errors because there are possible execution paths in the code, where even though the variables have not been assigned yet, you are already using them. And this can only be if you are not handling the registration, which is why it is anyway best to add a default to all your switch statements. It is defensive programming.

Comment: That makes sense. For switch statements, could i also use "else" in place of default or is default a better option?

Comment: You cannot use an else because it would not compile. else can only be used together with an if.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually initialized a local variable because it does not initialize by default.

You should initialize the variable `lodgingFee` before using it.
You should look like below code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal days = 0.0;
        decimal registrationFee = 0.0;
        decimal lodgingFee = 0.0;
        decimal total = 0.0;
        decimal lodgingCal = 0.0;
        string registration = "";
        ...............
        ...................
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign some default values to each variables.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal days = 0.0;
        decimal registrationFee = 0.0;
        decimal lodgingFee = 0.0;
        decimal total = 0.0;
        decimal lodgingCal = 0.0;

        string registration = String.Empty;
        //..............
    }
```